# What is efficient way of transforming map's keyset into vector of keys

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, stdmap

What is efficient way of transforming map's keyset into vector of keys
currently i am iterating over my map and adding iter.first into vector, is this similar to Java's KeySet api?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be something like this:

```
std::vector<KeyType> v;
std::map<KeyType, ValueType> m;

v.reserve(m.size());
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), [](const std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>& p) { return p.first; });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using boost, the Range library comes with a convenient [map_keys](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html) function, which takes away the need of a temporary `vector`.

A more general approach is putting some kind of transform_iterator on top of the `map` iterators (which is essentially what Boost.Range does).

Otherwise your approach of copying into a vector can be rewritten in terms of a `std::transform` call. Possibly preceded by `vector::reserve` to cut down on allocations.

If you don't have a transform iterator already, you probably want to use the last solution as the first two are rather hard to get right depending on how compatible with older standards you want to be.

Comment: but which one amongst these is the fastest?

Comment: @user1393608 Benchmark. It really depends on how you use it: in general iterating over the vector is going to be faster than iterating and transforming over the map. At the same time you will need to update the vector when the map changes and it requires more storage, while the transform iterator approach doesn't. Probably the bottom line will be: it doesn't matter for your particular application.

Comment: @user1393608: the one you *measure* and find faster than the other ones which you *also* measured.